# jQuery beforeunload

Tags: jquery, authentication, asp-classic

I have been rewriting a classic asp Shopping basket using jQuery and Ajax. My problem is i want a logout functionality when the user closes the browser. this works but if i refresh the page the code to logout fires and i lose everything. I found this jquery code piece:

```
    var inFormOrLink = false;
    $('a').live('click', function () { inFormOrLink = true; });
    $('form').bind('submit', function () { inFormOrLink = true; });
    $(window).bind("beforeunload", function () {
        if (inFormOrLink == false) {
            $.post("logout.asp");
        }

    })
```

Does anyone have any ideas how i can perform logout.asp ONLY when the user closes the browser OR indeed changes to a new website. But keep the information while in the Application (in IIS).

Answer (score 1):

The `beforeunload` is fired when you leave/refresh the current page, and you can only successfully run code that blocks the browsing session, such as `alert()` or `prompt()`.